# RESTcall with Restsharp does not work (using a Proxy)

Tags: c#, proxy, restsharp

I am trying to make a RESTcall in C# with Restsharp (V 106.6.10). When I am executing the code on my personal PC it works very well. But when I am executing the same code on another PC (for work), which is using a Proxy, it does not work anymore. I am getting the following error:

> Anfragefehler: Error calling TestPut: Unable to connect to the remote server (0)

`TestPut` is the method which should call the API
To solve that I have written the following code in my app.config. This should declare the proxy:

```
<system.net>
      <defaultProxy enabled="true">
      <proxy bypassonlocal="True"
             proxyaddress="http://[IP]:[Port]/"/>
      </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

I also tried to assign the Proxy in the constructor of my `APIclient` with:

```
WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("[IP]", [Port]);
request.Proxy = myproxy;
```

I also logged the ProxyURL and this seems to be correct...
What could be the error? Do you need any additional information? 
I am calling an endpoint from AWS and when I call this Endpoint in the Browser it works.

Thank you in advance
Lukas

Comment: Is there any login credentials for proxy?

Comment: I do not think so. Where can I see this? When I go to my proxy settings in Windows I do only see the IP and the Port..
Furthermore the errormessage displays in the brackets the statuscode of the request. I do think if any credentials for my proxy are needed, it should return the code "407" but it returns "0".. What could that mean?

Comment: Try to add useDefaultCredentials="true" in your web.config as an attribute to defaultProxy.